# CGF template in overleaf

Tags: overleaf

I just imported CGF template in overleaf.
And I found that the content file is the XXX-body.inc.
However, I can't open this inc file in overleaf, and can't edit its content.

I don't know how to do with it.
Can anyone give me some instructions on this?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: That's just a `.tex` file with a different extension.  Rename it and Overleaf should be able to show you the file

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for your reply. I renamed it, I can see the content of  it in overleaf, but still can't edit it.

Comment: Hi there, Tom from Overleaf Suppor here. I just provided an answer. If you still have issues, you can reach me at support@overleaf.com with the project URL and I'll have a deeper look. I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

*(Tom from Overleaf Support here.)*

Overleaf currently doesn't recognize the `.inc` extension as editable. One solution is to delete the file, create it manually using the **New File** icon (this way the file should be created editable), and paste its contents (copying from a local editor).

(The only caveat is that this won't work if you use the Git bridge, GitHub integration or if you have Dropbox active.)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I renamed it to tex.
But I still can't edit it in overleaf.

Comment: But please, add this information to your question (there's an `edit` button underneath). Funnily enough, if you download the project (click Menu, then Source), rename the file to `.tex`, then reupload it, it works... Ah, Tom just said that in his answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution:

- rename the existing `example.inc` file with `example.tex` extension and replace it with the `\input{example.inc}`
- now you can open the `.tex` file and see what is inside, but you cannot edit it
- now rename the `example.tex` with something else, and create a new `example.tex`, copy all the contents from the previous `example.tex`
- `voilà!` that's it. and do not ask me why and how it worked! Its a miracle! :P